# How to Set Multi-Select choices in admin django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

I have a model

```
class Event(models.Model):

    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    event_organizer = models.ForeignKey(Organizer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_city = models.ForeignKey(Citie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have a field event_tag. During add event form in admin panel i want to select multiple tags. how to do that and how to save them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined `event_tag` as ForeignKey to `Tag` model, you can't select multiple tags for one Event.

If you want to do so, however, you should define your `Event` model like this:

```py
class Event(models.Model):

    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    event_organizer = models.ForeignKey(Organizer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_city = models.ForeignKey(Citie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
```

Now if you register both `Event` and `Tag` model in the admin, you should be able to select multiple tags for one event.

#### Edit

As you mentioned in the comments, your `Tag` model has a `is_active` field and you want to limit the choices to those that are active.

This can be done using `limit_choices_to` in the M2M filed:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    #...
    event_tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', limit_choices_to={'is_active': True})
```

Comment: but how we get only active tags

Comment: I didn't get that. Do you mean that there is a `active` filed on `Tag` model and you want to limit the tag selection choices to just active ones?

Comment: yes. there is is_active field in Tag model. i want to show only is_active =  true